# Put same line position from multiple listboxes Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, search, listbox

I have the following phonebook.

I have 3 listbox for name, phone and email of contact. I want to put those data in the same order at the 3 search result listboxes. I only only know the contact name the search.

For example:

```
| Listbox 1 | Listbox 2 | Listbox 3 |
| Names     | phone     | Email     |
|           |           |           |


| Listbox 6     | Listbox 5      | Listbox  6     |
| Names results | Phones results | Emails results |
|               |                |                |
```

The code is:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton4.Click
    Dim resultado As String
    For Each resultado In ListBox1.Items
        If resultado.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ListBox6.Items.Add(resultado)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How can i do this?

Regards

Comment: where does "those data" come from.  lots of missing info

Comment: The names come from listbox 1 to listbox 6 (I got it already). I have phones at listbox 2 and i want the phone results at listbox 5, and emails listbox3 to listbox6.

Comment: since lots of information regarding your code is missing does `listbox1` ,`listbox2` and `listbox3` have any `id` column ? or why your using 3 separate `listbox`, in my opinion you can combine the `3- listboxes` into `1-listbox` by adding column for `name , phone , email` in  a single listbox

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `For Each` loop, use a `For` loop.  That way, you'll have the index of the current item being considered in `ListBox1` so you'll be able to get the items at the same index in `ListBox2` and `ListBox3` and add them to `ListBox5` and `ListBox6`.